# Mysql create with Like query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In the following Query in Mysql,

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` LIKE `student`
```

t1 which is created newly from student, will have same schema and foriegn keys as like as student or not. This is my doubt.

Can anyone clear my doubt ?

Comment: Why don't you just try? That way you settle the matter, one way or the other.

Comment: After doing your `CREATE TABLE t1 LIKE student;` do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE t1;` to examine it.

Answer (score 0):

Table t1 has same schema like student and foreign key but it is empty table. [Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

**For Detail,**

- You can create one table from another by adding a **SELECT** statement at
  the end of the CREATE TABLE statement:

**> CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;**

in this case, all data from original table are copied to new table but schema related information such as primay key contratint does not include.

---

- Use **LIKE** to create an **empty table** based on the definition of another
  table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the
  original table:

**> CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;**

In this case, new table has same schema as original table but has no data.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

> Use LIKE to create an empty table based on the definition of another table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the original table:
>
> CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
>
> The copy is created using the same version of the table storage format as the original table. The SELECT privilege is required on the original table.
>
> LIKE works only for base tables, not for views.
>
> CREATE TABLE ... LIKE does not preserve any DATA DIRECTORY or INDEX DIRECTORY table options that were specified for the original table, or any foreign key definitions.